# pandas cell "nan" considered a float

Tags: python, pandas

I have a row `Languages` that might contain `nan` values, this is a snippet of how the csv file is loaded

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename_and_path)

for _, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['Languages'].isnull():
        #split by / or ,
        print(row['Languages'])
        languages = list(row['Languages'].split('/').split(','))
```

and one row in the csv printout in pandas

```
City                         NaN
Hm PO Box                    NaN
City 2                       NaN
Tel                          NaN
Fax                          NaN
E-mail                       NaN
Languages                    NaN
```

since i want to process text in languages but it throws a `nan` error

```
In [2]: from guides.pandas_import import process_file

In [3]: process_file()
nan
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-029c48606bfe> in <module>
----> 1 process_file()

~/code/kpsga/guides/pandas_import.py in process_file(filename_and_path)
    42             #split by / or ,
    43             print(row['Languages'])
---> 44             languages = list(row['Languages'].split('/').split(','))
    45             languages = [x.lstrip() for x in languages]
    46 

AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'split'
```

tried checking using `isnull` and it didn't work

```
In [1]: from guides.pandas_import import process_file

In [2]: process_file()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-029c48606bfe> in <module>
----> 1 process_file()

~/code/kpsga/guides/pandas_import.py in process_file(filename_and_path)
    39         guide.email = row['E-mail']
    40 
---> 41         if row['Languages'].isnull():
    42             #split by / or ,
    43             print(row['Languages'])

AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'isnull'
```

is there a way to check it is a `nan` value possibly by loading the file to recognize them

Comment: Btw, there seems also logic problem, if missing values then want split? Maybe you think if not missing value then processing by split.